# How can I change the default location for bluetooth file transfers?

Tags: settings, bluetooth, file-transfer

I have an Android 2.3 device (Samsung Galaxy Y Duos, S6102) and want all files that I receive via bluetooth to save to my SD card.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default location is already on your external SD card in the /bluetooth folder.

**It's not possible to configure it up to Android 4.1 Jelly Bean**:
With the included stock bluetooth receiver you cannot change the location as of now, because it's hard coded. You need a 3rd party app like [Bluetooth file transfer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.medieval.blueftp) which might be configurable here.

In ./packages/apps/Bluetooth/src/com/android/bluetooth/opp/ you can see it.

Constants.java defines this:

```
public static final String DEFAULT_STORE_SUBDIR = "/bluetooth";
```

BluetoothOppReceiveFileInfo.java has no switch for the location:

```
File receiveFile = new File(uniqueFileName);
if (sDesiredStoragePath == null) {
    sDesiredStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +
        Constants.DEFAULT_STORE_SUBDIR;
}
```

Comment: The Bluetooth file transfer app works well.  You can change your home folder in settings and to get higher up the folder tree (to get to your ext SD) you need to use the back button (took me a while to figure that one out).  You may also need to change your destination folder in settings.  Just doing home alone won't cut it.

Comment: FYI, the default directory is not always on the external SD card.  (Mine was on my internal storage.  I deleted the folder `Bluetooth` on internal storage and created a new empty folder with the same name on the external SD card.  When I tried to transfer something, it ignored the external SD card and re-created the `Bluetooth` folder on the internal storage.)